# CSS Selector issue with list items

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am facing a problem with CSS selector. I have content in "list Items(`LI`)" and "list Items(LI)" having class"child". I need to style for first "list Items(LI)" with the class name ".child". only in `CSS`.

```css
ul{margin:0;padding:0 32px 0 32px}
li{ color:red;}
.child{
  color:green;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
}
li.child ~ .child{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  background:green;
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li class="child">
This need to be Red Color
  </li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no "first-of-class" type of selector in CSS - unfortunately this can't be done the way in which you intend. It would be better if you can use a unique identifier for your selector, e.g: `.first-child`, and then only apply this class to the first child in question.

Answer (score 1):

Update your css rules

```
ul{margin:0;padding:0 32px 0 32px}
li{ color:red;}

li.child{
  color:yellow;
  font-size:20px;
}
li.child ~ .child {
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with your class name then next element in it `.child > div`

Answer (score 0):

you want like this actually you have to take another `<ul>` because you're not targetting first-child of '' in the middle you want or else you can use `:nth-child(8)` without adding other `<ul>` list.

```css
ul{margin:0;padding:0 32px 0 32px}
li{ color:red;}
.child{
  color:green;
}
li.child:first-child{
  color:blue;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
  <li class="child">
  sub
  <div>
  I want differnt styles for this.
  </div>
  </li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its dynamic content, its may add li between li, with class name only this css need to apply.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
ul{margin:0;padding:0 32px 0 32px}
li{ color:red;}
.child{
  color:green;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
}
li.child ~ .child{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  background:green;
  width:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li>hellow</li>
  <li class="child">
This need to be Red Color
  </li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li class="child">sub text</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I got solution for red color for specified text below.[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srinivashappy/0nzmtut7/)

```
<li class="child">
This need to be Red Color
  </li>
```